# VirtualBox anaconda installation failing

Tags: anaconda, virtualbox, anaconda3

Having trouble installing anaconda on my Ubuntu VirtualBox. Have tried rebooting and have tried assigning a bigger chunk of base memory but still failing at the final few hurdles.

> ```
> Unpacking payload ...
> concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                                                    
> '''
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 368, in _queue_management_worker
>   File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
> '''
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
>   File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
>   File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
>   File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
>   File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
> concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or
> ```
>
> pending.
> [1981] Failed to execute script entry_point